# Why isn't my state hook updating correctly?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I've created a minimal cutting of my code to show the issue, seen below.

```
const PlayArea = (props) => {
  const [itemsInPlay, setItemsInPlay] = useState([
      {id: 'a'},
      {id: 'b'}
  ]);

  const onItemDrop = (droppedItem) => {
    setItemsInPlay([...itemsInPlay, droppedItem]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Dropzone onDrop={onItemDrop} />
      <div>
        {itemsInPlay.map(item => (
          <span
            key={item.id}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

The dropzone detects a drop event and calls `onItemDrop`. However, for reasons I don't understand, I can only drop in one item. The first item I drop is correctly appended to `itemsInPlay` and it re-renders correctly with a third span in addition to the starting two.

However, any subsequent item I drop *replaces the third item* rather than being appended. It's as though `onItemDrop` had a stored reference to `itemsInPlay` which was frozen with the initial value. Why would that be? It should be getting updated on re-render with the new value, no?

Comment: Can you show the content of `Dropzone`?

Comment: Sure, but it's a bit longer with more references to additional code. I removed the typing and made the code more generic to share here above. https://pastebin.com/GPeBry1v

Comment: I'm reasonably sure if I remove the dropzone and add a button that just appends a random item to the array when `onClick` is called, the problem would be the same. But I don't know for sure yet.

Comment: is the prop called `onDrop` or `onCardDrop`?

Comment: Like I said, I had made it more generic to share here-- the calls all line up with correct names in the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dropzone sets its subscription token only once, when the component is initially rendered. When that occurs, the callback passed to `setSubscriptionToken` contains a *stale* value of the `onCardDrop` prop - it will not automatically update when the component re-renders, since the subscription was added only once.

You could either unsubscribe and resubscribe every time `onCardDrop` changes, using `useEffect`, or use the callback form of `setItemsInPlay` instead:

```
const onItemDrop = (droppedItem) => {
  setItemsInPlay(items => [...items, droppedItem]);
};
```

This way, even if an old version of `onItemDrop` gets passed around, the function won't depend on the *current* binding of `itemsInPlay` being in the closure.

Another way to solve it would be to change `Dropzone` so that it subscribes not just once, but *every time* the `onCardDrop` changes (and unsubscribing at the end of a render), with `useEffect` and a dependency array.

Regardless of what you do, it would also be a good idea to unsubscribe from subscriptions when the PlayArea component dismounts, something like:

```
const [subscriptionToken, setSubscriptionToken] = useState<string | null>(null);
useEffect(
    () => {
        const callback = (topic: string, dropData: DropEventData) => {
            if (wasEventInsideRect(dropData.mouseUpEvent, dropZoneRef.current)) {
                onCardDrop(dropData.card);
                setDroppedCard(dropData.card);
            }
        };
        setSubscriptionToken(PubSub.subscribe('CARD_DROP', callback));
        return () => {
            // Here, unsubscribe from the CARD_DROP somehow,
            // perhaps using `callback` or the subscription token
        };
    },
    [] // run main function once, on mount. run returned function on unmount.
);
```

Comment: I can give this a shot. -- but given that the array is updating with the correct card each time, doesn't that imply a non-stale value is getting passed through, and the issue has to do with the state in `PlayArea`? Otherwise I would expect the array to keep expanding with stale references if the problem were as you have described, rather than to be capped at three items.

Comment: The array is updating, but `Dropzone`'s subscription callback, which is only set on mount, references the `onCardDrop` on mount - and, at that point, the `onCardDrop` references the initial state with only 2 items in the array. No matter how the state updates later, the initial state - which the callback closes over - will still contain only those 2 items.

Comment: IOW: Dropzone's *render* is using the props passed down (up-to-date), but the subscription callback is only set *once*, initially, so the state it references becomes out of date.

Comment: Let me digest that and go look at it again. Will report back!

Comment: Thought I commented back before, guess not-- you were exactly correct! Thanks! Good eye.